# Customize Boostrap 3 carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I changed the bootstrap carousel default settings from the default chevron-left to menu-left and right. and I added image links. i changed the default height to 270px and change it to container.

My issue is that the arrows float to the top as well as the image links, also when they scroll through the links the links scroll past the arrows when changing.

```
#carousel-wrap {
    background-color: #0b0b0b;
    height: 270px;
}

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right{
background: none !important;
filter: progid:none !important;
}

<section id="carousel-wrap">
  <div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide container" data-ride="carousel">      
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
        <img src="resources/media/referrals/hub-logo.png" alt="First slide image" class="center-block">          
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        <img src="resources/media/referrals/hub-logo.png" alt="Second slide image" class="center-block">         
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        <img src="resources/media/referrals/hub-logo.png" alt="Third slide image" class="center-block">          
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        <img src="resources/media/referrals/hub-logo.png" alt="Third slide image" class="center-block">          
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
      </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center arrows vertically you can use `line-height` property (height of your carousel):

```
.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
  background: none !important;
  line-height: 270px;
}
```

For image you can use this technique:

```
.item {
  height: 270px;
}
.item img {
  max-height: 100%;  
  max-width: 100%; 
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0;  
  bottom: 0;  
  left: 0;  
  right: 0;  
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: makshh how can i adjust the fade so the image dont slide under the arrows

Comment: the arrows go down but not the image in the middle

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: ok the image in between the arrows that actually slide is aligned at the top also

Comment: the problem is when the image slides it goes under the arrows can i make it disappear before it goes under

Comment: You can move arrows outside of the container.